# Downloading Image from Url's Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

Hope you are all doing good. Guys i have a doubt ihave image url, In xml, i created a button called download, when i click the button the image in the url should download in users device.I will provide the code, i tried this method, but when i click the dwnload button it's showing only permission denied. I also checked the settings there is no permission requested.
I used intent to pass the url from another activity. I also did not get any dialog box for permission also. In manifest file i used this
INTERNET,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
**For demo you can use this image url https://d2a5isokysfowx.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/que-es-android-studio-scaled-1200x900.jpg**

```
package com.example.myapplication;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class RadarMapFullView extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.0f;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Button btnDownload;

    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_radar_map_full_view);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageViewFullSize);
        scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new ScaleListener());
        btnDownload = findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);

        String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("IMAGE_URL");

        // Load image from URL using Picasso (for non-GIF images)
        if (!imageUrl.endsWith(".gif")) {
            Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
        } else {
            // For GIF images, consider using a library like Glide that supports GIF
            Glide.with(this).asGif().load(imageUrl)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .skipMemoryCache(true)
                    .into(imageView);
        }

        btnDownload.setOnClickListener(v -> checkPermissionAndDownload());
    }

    private void checkPermissionAndDownload() {
        // Check for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission already granted, proceed with download
                downloadImage();
            } else {
                // Request permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
            }
        } else {
            // Permission automatically granted on lower Android versions, proceed with download
            downloadImage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission granted, proceed with download
                downloadImage();
            } else {
                // Permission denied, show a toast or handle it accordingly
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied. Cannot download image.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void downloadImage() {
        // Execute the AsyncTask to download the image
        new DownloadImageTask().execute(getIntent().getStringExtra("IMAGE_URL"));
    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            String imageUrl = params[0];

            try {
                URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                // Get the file name from the URL
                String fileName = imageUrl.substring(imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

                // Create a directory if not exists
                File directory = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "YOUR_APP_NAME");
                if (!directory.exists()) {
                    directory.mkdirs();
                }

                // Create the file in the directory
                File file = new File(directory, fileName);

                // Download the image
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                output.close();
                input.close();

                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if (result) {
                Toast.makeText(RadarMapFullView.this, "Image downloaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(RadarMapFullView.this, "Failed to download image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        return true;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        private float MIN_SCALE_FACTOR = 0.5f;

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector) {
            mScaleFactor *= scaleGestureDetector.getScaleFactor();
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE_FACTOR, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));

            // Apply the scale factor to the ImageView
            imageView.setScaleX(mScaleFactor);
            imageView.setScaleY(mScaleFactor);

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if (!directory.exists()) {
                   if(! directory.mkdirs()) return;
                }

Comment: Is this about downloading or about creating a file? Please elaborate.

Comment: Is about downloading the image from the url, and store it in the device.

Comment: Also I used scale gesture for image zoom in and zoom out, I tried zoom control dependencies,but while I use this in XML, it shows only error.

Comment: `when i click the dwnload button it's showing only permission denied.` Which permission that you need to download a file is denied? I ask again: is the problem with downloading or with creating a file?

Comment: So if you click the download button i see that you check permissions. Is the permission denied while checking permissions? Which permissions? Which is denied?

Comment: Also for getExternalFilesDir() you do not need any permission to create files or folders there so i'm quite puzzled about which permission this post is about.

Comment: I thought for downloading image we need to have the permission WRITE_EXTERNAL.

Comment: Now I downloaded the image, thanks for the clarification

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for questions/issues related to the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.